# Kinetic JS dragging a layer causes shapes on another layer to stop responding to drag

Tags: javascript, canvas, draggable, kineticjs

I have been developing an app using Kinetic which uses several layers to keep things organised and I have draggable elements in more than one layer. I am finding that when one layer is dragged, shapes on another layer are no longer draggable.

In the cut-down example supplied, the blue Rects in the upper layer are no longer draggable once the lower layer has been dragged, I can't see why this is.

I have tried looking through the documentation and various tutorials, asking on Stackoverflow is my last resort so I hope someone can help!

I have tried setting dragOnTop to false on the draggable layer by the way, this doesn't change the result.

Thanks,
Oscar

http://jsfiddle.net/EveryoneMustWin/QRaxJ/

```
var kItems = {};

kItems.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: $("#container").width(),
    height: $("#container").height()
});

kItems.lowerLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    scale: 1.0,
    id: "lower",
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        return {
            x: pos.x,
            y: pos.y
        }
    }
});

kItems.upperLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({
    scale: 1.0,
    id: "upper"
});

kItems.stage.add(kItems.lowerLayer);
kItems.stage.add(kItems.upperLayer);

kItems.backdrop = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 50, 
    y: 50, 
    width: 200, 
    height: 200,
    stroke: '#822',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: '#b62',
    opacity: 1,
    id: 'backdrop'
});

kItems.lowerLayer.add(kItems.backdrop);

kItems.block1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    stroke: '#228',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: '#65b',
    opacity: 1,
    id: 'block1',
    draggable: true
});

kItems.upperLayer.add(kItems.block1);

kItems.block2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 180,
    y: 100,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    stroke: '#228',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fill: '#65b',
    opacity: 1,
    id: 'block2',
    draggable: true
});

kItems.upperLayer.add(kItems.block2);

kItems.lowerLayer.draw();
kItems.upperLayer.draw();

kItems.lowerLayer.on("dragmove", function() {
    kItems.upperLayer.setAttrs({x:this.getX(), y:this.getY()});
    kItems.upperLayer.draw();
});
```

Comment: Yep, I confirm it's misbehaving.  It works without error in kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js, but misbehaves in kinetic-v4.4.3.min.js.  You might want to submit a bug report: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues

Comment: Thanks markE, I have submitted a bug report. I hadn't realised that 4.3.3 was working actually so I've been able to drop back to that version for now.

Comment: v4.4 something changed. 4.3.3. is the last version that this was working properly. What I have found is that the other layer's hit canvas becomes empty and that is the reason it's not responding to drag & drop any longer. When I call layer.drawHit() for the unresponsive layer, it starts working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround before this is fixed was to call layer.drawHit() on my dragEnd handler for the layer that became unresponsive (see my comment above). This has made it possible for me to continue using the newest version (there are many nice improvements that I didn't want to lose by using 4.3.3). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good workaround for 4.4.3! I wouldn't have been able to guess that this was possible.